# Software for creating data structure diagrams?

Tags: data-structures, visualization

What's a good (preferably free) software tool for creating data structure diagrams? For example, something like this:
[image]

Comment: Heh. Uhm, I might get slammed for this so it's just a comment: Visio (Seriously -- chances are your boss will use it [only know it] anyway ;-)

Comment: I've tried Visio but I couldn't find the shapes I was looking for. Does it have a "one column multiple row table"-like shape?

Comment: no, but copy/paste is a wonderful thing :-)

Answer (score 6):

[GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/datastruct.html) may suit you.

Comment: Depends on how much you want to fine-tune the layout.  If you want something like your picture then graphviz is an excellent choice; particularly since maintaining the picture is really easy.  (Update the text input file & it re-draws every time).  But you can't twiddle with result.  Visio/Dia better if you want to fine tune picture.  Also look at yEd (http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) which is very good, open source and cross platform.

Comment: @sfinnie yED was really really nice!

Comment: @sfinnie Just a correction: while yEd is a really nice tool, and freely available, it is not open source, unless I missed something.

Answer (score 6):

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) takes a bit of learning, but is quite good for this.

A simpler program is [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia)